# TS2339: Property 'navigator' does not exist on type 'Global'

Tags: typescript

```
interface Global {
    navigator: any;
}    

it('navigator is undefined', () => {
    delete global.navigator;
    expect(navigator).toBe(undefined);
});
```

on the line `delete global.navigator`, typescript is throwing the following error `TS2339: Property 'navigator' does not exist on type 'Global'.` Basing on some StackOverflow post I declared `Global` type. But it did not solve the issue. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you within a module? If you, you will need to wrap the interface extension like this:

```
declare global {
    interface Global {
        navigator: any;
    }
}
```

Otherwise you create a new interface called `Global` scoped to the module, rather than extending the existing global one.